# How to write python wrapper for web interface?

Tags: python

If I want to give input to the website through python program and display the result on terminal after online computation then how can I do it using python wrapper? As I am new to python, so Can anyone suggest me some tutorial for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on the website that you want to retrieve your result from, and how it accepts input from you. For example, if your webpage accepts GET or POST requests, then you can send it a HTTP request and print out the response onto terminal.

If your website accepts input via a submit form, on the other hand, you would have to find the link of the submit button and send your data to that page.

There is a Python library called [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), which you can use to send HTTP requests to a webpage and get the response. I suggest you read its documentation, it has some good examples that you can base your idea off. Another library is the inbuilt [urllib2](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), which would also work for your purposes.

The response to your request is most likely to be a HTTP webpage, so you may have to scrape out your desired content from inside that.